# Typescript perform regular expression match from string

Tags: regex, typescript

I need to perform a regular expression match and the expression is given as a string as part of user input.  For example to validate an expression for email it will come in as `'/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/'`.  Note the `'` at the start and end.  Now to perform the validation I run the following code

```
var expression = inputExpression // in this case its '/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/'
const matches = inputString.match(expression)
```

However this always fails since the regular expression has a starting and ending `'` in the string.  I tried doing this with something like

```
let re = new RegExp(expression)
```

But still this fails.  Is there an elegant way of doing this rather stripping out the starting and ending `'` manually ?

Comment: You mean that effectively `inputExpression = "'/^\\S+@\\S+\\.\\S+$/'"`?

Comment: correct it ends up with a starting and ending '

Comment: Then you'd need to strip both the `'` and `/` characters from it before trying to convert to a RegExp e.g. `re = new RegExp(inputExpression.replace(/(^'\/|\/'$)/g, ''))`